# Remove one character in a column with comparison query

Tags: mysql

I need a query that removes the period "." of the column clientFName.

My query is:

```
SELECT clientFName, clientMName 
FROM dto_client_dtl 
WHERE clientFName LIKE '.%';
```

My table is the following:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you add your sql query atleast instead of inserting picture.?

Comment: First edit your question properly by adding sample data and the sql query which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `UPDATE` the table removing the first character for those rows that `clientFName` has period "." as the first character.

```
UPDATE dto_client_dtl
SET clientFName = SUBSTR(clientFName, 2)
WHERE clientFName LIKE '.%';
```

Comment: may i know what is the function of 2 in (clientFname, 2) in that query?

Comment: It removes the first character. You can find more info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: Thanks for that! You are so great!

Comment: after removing the period, how can i return it back?

Comment: This query will update the table. To select it you have to use SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `Replace`

```
Replace(col,'.','')
```

Try this query:-

```
select * from table where Replace(col,'.','') like "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only for display try **trim**:

```
SELECT TRIM( LEADING  '.' FROM clientFName ) ,clientMName
FROM dto_client_dtl where clientFName like '.%'
```

Comment: Thanks! It really works!